# Talend - CSV file to Postgres

Tags: java, csv, components, postgresql-9.1, talend

I am trying to upload a csv file into postgres using Talend, I am getting an error in tPostgresqlOutput component during this process

Please help me to fix this issue

```
Execution failed : Job compile errors 
At least job "Phase_1_data_movement" has a compile errors, please fix and export again.
Error Line: 1297
Detail Message: pstmt_tPostgresqlOutput_1 cannot be resolved
There may be some other errors caused by JVM compatibility. Make sure your JVM setup is similar to the studio.
Job Phase_1_data_movement ended at 11:39 27/04/2017. [exit code=0]
```

Comment: what is the code you are seeing in line 1297? please click on the code button in the design palette and see what exactly is the error in code

Comment: Without a picture of your job layout this will be difficult to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When you look at the java code (which is in the center tab behind the designer tab) you'll see that there is a variable pstmt_tPostgresqlOutput_1 that is used but not defined. 
So this code will not compile.

This code is generated by Talend and you cannot change it by  editing the text AFAIK. The question is what causes Talend to generate faulty code?

In my case it was that i had not defined the 'schema' or metadata of my input file. Once i had defined the column names and data types of my input-file, the code generated by Talend was error-free.